# How to "start" a job in Rails upon launch

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, ruby-on-rails-4, recurrence

Using https://github.com/facto/fist_of_fury to execute recurring tasks (cool little gem!). The instructions say that once you schedule jobs, "somewhere, you need to kick off the process" with `FistOfFury.attack!`

That was a bit vaguely worded, so I wanted to get some thoughts on where the statement `FistOfFury.attack!` goes... I guess I'm confused because where/ what is the "start" point? I'm using Heroku, so it is when the Heroku server boots up (which is when I understand the `initializer` files are run).

Anyways, thoughts welcome on whether this line of code `FistOfFury.attack!` should be in:

- `config/application.rb` as part of the configurations that are run in `class Application end` (this is the same as putting it in the `config/environments` I gather, but I'd rather have it here to avoid writing it twice, for dev and production environments
- `config/initializers/fistoffury.rb` as its own file
- ... some totally different place

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK in this case for Fist of Fury, since the whole point is that the gem runs within one process, the answer is an initializer file. Fortunately, the author has amended the README with a rails generator command that will create the necessary initializer for you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Foreman. Foreman can help manage multiple processes that your Rails app depends upon when running in development. It also provides an export command to move them into production.

/config/initializers/* should be used for configuration settings for frameworks and gems (see: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/configuring.html).

config/application.rb feels uncomfortable because I wouldn’t think to look there to see an external job start.

Since you’re already using Heroku, its just a matter of modifying your Procfile.

See:

http://railscasts.com/episodes/281-foreman

https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/procfile

http://blog.daviddollar.org/2011/05/06/introducing-foreman.html

Comment: Actually after watching this, I might just be confused, but it seems like I would have the same problem... somewhere I need to say `foreman start`. But I also realized, since I only have 1 command, it might be overkill to use foreman, can I just state in the Procfile.text `web: FistofFury.attack!` after the server declaration?

Comment: Heroku runs foreman start. You need to create a rake task to run FirstofFury since you can't have ruby code in a procfile.